# Using append in $.each shows whole array

Tags: jquery, arrays, append

Okay, so I have an array of characters and i'm wanting them to display one at a time. This is the code i'm trying to use:

```
$.each(characterarray, function( index, value ){
   $("div").fadeOut(300).delay( 10 ).append( value ).fadeIn(300);
});
```

So instead of fading out, waiting, append one of the array, and fade in.

It would: fade out, wait, append all of the array, and fade in.

When I used

```
alert( value );
```

and it would apply an alert for each letter, but when I tried the to append it would show all of the array at once.

Comment: Instead of starting all animations in the loop, it would be better to start one animation, and give it a callback function that starts the next one, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop finishes immediately, you'll have to increment the delay

```
$.each(characterarray, function( index, value ){
     $("div").delay(index*1000).fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).append( value ).delay(10).fadeIn(300);
     });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hL9UB/1/)

Comment: Alternate solution using the fx queue: http://jsfiddle.net/hL9UB/2/ I think i preferr yours though.

Comment: I tried doing the one by adeneo, but the code in the post doesn't work. For some reason the page remains blank until all of the code has run and then it fades in the results of it all finished. Instead of doing it one character at a time.(If that makes sense) The Fiddle code works, but is it possible to make it use one div instead of a new div for each character?

Comment: @Random-citizen - Not sure I get it, but something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/hL9UB/3/

Comment: @adeneo, The second script you posted(The one that uses a div for each character) works perfectly, but i'm trying to create something that works a bit more dynamically. When I use the code in the post (The one without .eq()) the page stays blank while it runs, after about 9 seconds(1 second per character) it fades in the entire sentence.

Comment: @adeneo Here is what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/7wuSJ/ (wait a few seconds for it to popup)

Comment: Well, yeah! That's because that version won't work with just one element, for one element incrementing the delay won't work, the animations have to be stacked, and the easiest way to do that would be a recursive function, and it's just as "dynamic" as a loop, perhaps even more so?

Comment: @adeneo, Okay thanks. I think I found away to not have to create a div for each character manually and still use your code. Thanks for helping.